# text response from get request into a python pandas data frame excluding begin and end lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, I am working on code that performs a get request from an api and returns the response in a text format and when I use

```
print(response.text)
```

I get the response in the below format -

```
ResponseBegin
Name|Age|Gender|Country
"ABC"|23|M|USA
"ABCD"|21|F|CAN
ResponseEnd
```

Can anyone please advise how to convert this into a pandas dataframe and also remove the ResponseBegin and ResponseEnd lines at the beginning and ending making the second row as the column header using | as a delimiter.

Thank you very much for your advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's more helpful if you do not show what `print(response.text)` contains, but just what `response.text` contains, since the print function is doing some formatting for human readability.

But I will assume that `response.text` is just a single string that looks like this:

```py
'ResponseBegin\nName|Age|Gender|Country\n"ABC"|23|M|USA\n"ABCD"|21|F|CAN\nResponseEnd'
```

Notice the `\n`, which is the "newline" character.

There are several ways to solve this, but the easiest (fewest lines of code) I think is to export it to a CSV file and then read it in:

```py
with open('mydf.csv', 'w') as fh:
   fh.write(response.text)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mydf.csv', sep='|', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1)
```

You can read more about [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for all of its handy tools, but here I am using:

- `sep`: the thing to use as a separator, `|` in your case
- `skiprows`/`skipfooter`: the number of lines at the beginning or end to skip